# Search for a text accross all revision of a file

Tags: git

I have a file which contained some text at some point which was then deleted.

I forgot which exact commit and in what branch it existed.

Is there any way to search all revisions of a file *accross all the branches* and find a commit where file contains specific text?

Comment: `git log -p FILE` to show the diffenrence (as a patch), then you can easily search the result for the specific text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you can use the -S option to [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log -S'bar' -- foo.rb
```

This search the text `bar` in the file `foo.rb`

if you want to search through all diffs you can do: `git log -G'bar' -- foo.rb`

> When -S or -G finds a change, show all the changes in that changeset, not just the files that contain the change in .

**NOTE**: This search is **casesensitive**.

If you add `-i` you can search case insensitive. Making the complete command:

```
git log -i -S'bar' -- foo.rb
```

**NOTE 2**: This searches only in your current branch.

If you want to search accross all branch you should add the `--all` flag

> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/, along with HEAD, are listed on the command line as .

The complete command will be:

```
git log --all -i -S'bar' -- foo.rb
```

The output will be something like this:

```
$ git log --all -i -S'bar' -- foo.rb

commit 53106e9cd319a2d8f960a3bbf2731acd0699a54f (feature/x)
Author: name <email>
Date:   Fri Jan 18 13:59:32 2019 +0100

    Added word
```

Comment: It search in current branch history only. E.g. I create another branch where I commit a file with `blablablah`, then I switch back to master and run the command. `git log -S'blablablah'` returns nothing, when I'd expect to see `branch X, commit 124abcf16`

Comment: You should add the `--all` option :) i've updated the answer

Comment: Also note that if the file was renamed and/or copied, you might look at the `-M` and `-C` command-line options.